# Laravel 8 redirect web routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

It seems there is an error in my Laravel 8 routes somewhere.

My web routes file:

```
Route::get('/{locale}', function ($locale) {
  if(!in_array($locale, ['en','nl','ru','uk','fr','de','es','pt','it']))
    abort(400);

  App::setLocale($locale);

  return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/', function () {
  return redirect('/en');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->get('/dashboard/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    if(!in_array($locale, ['en','nl','ru','uk','fr','de','es','pt','it']))
      abort(400);

    App::setLocale($locale);

    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
  return redirect('/dashboard/en');
});
```

When going to `/`, it is redirected to `/en`.
But when going to `/dashboard` it isn't redirected to `/dashboard/en` but gives an error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard
```

As can be seen, not a lot of information given.

Anyone knows what to do?

Comment: btw, you can use a regex pattern on that route parameter so you don't have to check it in every route that needs that restriction on locale values

Comment: It will probably only contain those 2 routes. But indeed. I will keep it in mind for the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

Laravel handles routes from top to bottom. Which means it gets to `/{locale}` before it gets to `/dashboard`. In this case `dashboard` is seen as `{locale}` and the wrong route is taken.